# Streaming video with PHP from server

Tags: php, streaming, video-streaming

I need to stream selected video files on the web server to clients.  I am using a PHP script to stream these files as requested, but I am running into an issue where if I am on a local net, it works fine, but if I am remote, it stutters. eg. it appears to load the stream, stop, load more, stop, etc. until enough media is available to play.  I am new to this stuff, so I need some advise on how to overcome this issue.  The bandwidth should not be a problem, so I am not sure what is going on.  I have tried several php streamers, but all act pretty much the same.  I am using videojs to display it within the client.

```
<?php
use vendor\videojswidget\VideoJsWidget;
$url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/site/putvideo');
$currentVideo = '';
$script1 = "function playAnotherVideo(){
    var source = document.getElementById('fileSelector');
    var path = source.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {file: path},
        url: '" .$url. "',
        success: function(result){
            var video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
            video.src = result;
            alert(result);
            video.load();
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}";

$this->registerJs($script1, yii\web\View::POS_END, 'my-options');

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'View Vault Lecture Capture System';
?>
<div class="site-index" style="background-color: black; color: yellow;">

    <div style="background-color: black;">  
        </br></br></br></br>     
        <h1 align="center">Welcome to the TEKVOX Lecture Capture System</h1>
        </br></br></br></br> 
    </div>
    <div class="body-content">
        <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left;">
        </br></br>
        <label for="fileselector" style="margin-left: 4em; width: 10em; 
            font-weight: bold; color: #FFFF00;">Video_Files</label>
        <select id="fileSelector" onchange="playAnotherVideo()" size="10em" 
        style="margin-left: 0em; color: #FFFF00; background-color: #000000; 
        border-color: #FFFFFF">
<?php
        if ($handle = opendir('c:/users/admin/videos/')) {

            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

                if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && 
                    strtolower(substr($entry, strrpos($entry, '.') + 1)) == 
                       'mp4' ){       
                    echo "<option value='$entry'>" .$entry. "</option>";
                }
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
?>
</select>
</div>
<span id="divplayer" style="margin-left: 20em;">
<?php

echo VideoJsWidget::widget([
    'options' => [
        'class' => '',
        'id' => 'videoPlayer',
        'poster' => "GreenX.png",
        'controls' => true,
        'preload' => 'none',
        'width' => '800',
        'height' => '450',
    ],
    'tags' => [
        'source' => [
            ['src' => '', 'type' => 'video/mp4'],
        ],
        'track' => [
            ['kind' => 'captions', 'src' => 
'http://vjs.zencdn.net/vtt/captions.vtt', 'srclang' => 'en', 'label' => 
'English']
        ]
    ]
]); 

?>
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
</br>
```

The getVideo.php code:

```
<?php
include_once "videoStream.php";
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
if($filename == '')
    return;
$file = "c:\\users\\admin\\videos\\" .$filename;

 $stream = new VideoStream($file);
 $stream->start();
```

?>

The VideoStream.php class I am currently trying out is at:
[VideoStream](https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293)

What is also strange is that the bar at the bottom of the player seems to indicate that the video is buffered, yet the player still stutters.  Not sure what that means.

Comment: It'd help if you share what you tried so far, including sample code.

Comment: Have you looked into http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html and https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module, PHP is not really well suited for what you want, it adds a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is typical of video delivery over a low or intermittent bandwidth connection.

The approaches to resolve this are typically quite sophisticated but on the server side built into readily available streaming servers, e.g: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org

You also may benefit from using a CDN like cloud front or Akami etc - these are basically designed to create copies of your content at the edge of the network to improve response times for users.